# Need help optimizing a query on a long table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[readings] 
(
    [facilityId] int NOT NULL ,
    [deviceId] int NOT NULL ,
    [reading] real NULL ,
    [insertionTimestamp] datetime2(7) NOT NULL 
)
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [readings_index] 
    ON [dbo].[readings] ([facilityId] ASC, [deviceId] ASC) 
GO
```

I have no primary keys. If I had they would be `facilityId`, `deviceId` and `insertionTimestamp`. But i am afraid of making it validate the uniqueness of these fields at each INSERTion in the table, making insertions much slower.

The problem I am having is that this table is very very long. At this moment I have almost one million records, and it takes 8 seconds resolving the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(reading) as reading, deviceId, 
    FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') as TS, 
    DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp) as year
FROM
    readings
WHERE 
    deviceId IN (12, 15, 18, 19, 22, 27, 28, 29, 32, 35, 36, 39, 42, 43, 46, 47, 50, 53, 54, 57, 61, 64, 65, 68, 71, 72, 75, 76, 79, 80, 83, 86, 87) 
    AND facilityId = 1 
    AND insertionTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-04 23:12:22.121' AND '2016-10-05 23:12:22.138'
GROUP BY 
    deviceId, FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'), 
    DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp)
```

The device ids and insertionTimestamp BETWEEN boundaries are different each time this query is executed.

I tried to have a look at EXPLAIN to see if I could optimize anything... Nothing comes to my mind.

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: A `NONCLUSTERED` index on insertionTimestamp would definitely help, but you'll still have that trade off between INSERT speed and READ/QUERY speed.  Which is more important?

Comment: reads are far more important, but insertions also need to happen within a reasonable time span (and I bet long time inserts would also impact ongoing read operations). You are suggesting creating a `NONCLUSTERED` index just for the insertionTimestamp column? Can you briefly explain the reasoning behind that so that I can learn from it? Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily recommending that over all other options.  I would also consider a `NONCLUSTERED` index on all 3 of the columns.  I would perform some testing myself, perhaps moving the data off into a temp/alternate table, applying the index with a single column, testing both `INSERT` and `SELECT` performance.  Then, I would apply the index to all 3 columns (removing other single column index), repeat the testing and then determine the most reasonable course of action.

Comment: How many records do you get when you only have the `deviceId in (12,...` part of the query and is it fast? I mean without the date format, just select reading, not even max reading

Comment: Depending how many rows there are per group, adding `reading` to a covering index might help.

Comment: Also, would it be feasible to either pre-calculate the results, or insert filtered and formatted data into another table?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but something like this might improve the speed if the inner select filters out most of the data and you run the calculations on the outer query, which will run on a much smaller dataset. But if the inner select returns 7 million out of 8 million records, it might even make it worse:

```
SELECT MAX(reading) as reading, deviceId, FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') as TS, DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp) as year
FROM (SELECT reading, deviceID, insertionTimestamp
       FROM readings
       WHERE deviceId IN (12,15,18,19,22,27,28,29,32,35,36,39,42,43,46,47,50,53,54,57,61,64,65,68,71,72,75,76,79,80,83,86,87) 
       AND facilityId = 1 ) i
WHERE insertionTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-04 23:12:22.121' AND '2016-10-05 23:12:22.138'
GROUP BY deviceId, FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'), DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp)
```

Comment: I think your missing a join clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having all three `where` columns in the index, although only two can be used directly.  And then, just throw in the extra column from the `SELECT`.

The time frame looks relatively small, so perhaps that should be the second column:  `readings(facilityId, insertionTimestamp, deviceId, reading)`.  Note that the last two could just be included in the index and not be made keys.

```
SELECT MAX(reading) as reading, deviceId,
       FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') as TS, 
       DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp) as year
FROM readings
WHERE deviceId IN (12,15,18,19,22,27,28,29,32,35,36,39,42,43,46,47,50,53,54,57,61,64,65,68,71,72,75,76,79,80,83,86,87) AND
      facilityId = 1 AND
      insertionTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-04 23:12:22.121' AND '2016-10-05 23:12:22.138'
GROUP BY deviceId, FORMAT(insertionTimestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'), DATEPART(year, insertionTimestamp);
```